# Should I use got or gotten?

Tags: got-gotten

Violence has got worst over the years.
Or 
Violence has gotten worst over the years.

Comment: Are you speaking American English or British English?

Answer (score -3):

*Gotten* is the past participle of *to get*, so to form the present perfect (the tense you are forming with *has _*) you would use it. Alternatively "Violence *got* worse over the years" would be correct, making it plain old past tense instead.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer received 3 downvotes as it doesn't answer the question. Please visit [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and see how it works here. I advise you to delete your answer. The question itself is closed.